# load html after opacity = 0

Tags: jquery

I have this code. opacity 0 and opacity 1 works! but load(pagina) don't load. Why?

```
function cargarContenido(pagina) {
    $('#content').animate({"opacity":"0"});
    if ($('#content').css('opacity') == 0) {
        $("#content").load(pagina);
    }
    $('#content').animate({ "opacity": "1" });
}
```

If i put only this, it works fine

```
function cargarContenido(pagina) {
    $("#content").load(pagina);
}
```

Comment: `console.log($('#content').css('opacity'))` are you sure it returns 0 ? (and the previous animation is asynchronous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the callback parameters of the `animate` and `load` methods to execute your code in sequence. Try this:

```
function cargarContenido(pagina) {
    $('#content').animate(
        { "opacity": "0" }, 
        function() {
            $("#loadimage").show(); // show a loading image
            // load content when opacity = 0 animation finished
            $("#content").load(
                pagina, 
                function() {
                    $("#loadimage").hide(); // hide a loading image
                    // make opacity = 1 when content has been loaded
                    $('#content').animate({ "opacity": "1" });
                }
            )
        }
    );
}
```

Note I've expanded the formatting of this code to make it clear what's happening. You can remove a lot of the spacing to make it shorter if required.

Comment: you are the best!!!! thank you so much!!! Only one more question... Its posibble insert load.gif while html is loading?

Comment: It is indeed, I'll update my answer for you. Don't forget to mark one of these answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`animate()` is asynchronous, so when you're checking the opacity it's not zero, as the animate function has'nt finished yet. You can use the callback in animate to do the same thing after the opacity has finished animating:

```
function cargarContenido(pagina) {
    $('#content').animate({"opacity":"0"}, function() {
        $(this).load(pagina, function() {
            $(this).animate({ "opacity": "1" });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the stuff after completing the animation in the callback function, Because it will run after completing the animation. [Read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) about the `complete` function ,

```
   $('#content').animate({"opacity":"0"},500,function(){
                     $("#content").load(pagina,function(){
                         $('#content').animate({ "opacity": "1" });
                     });             
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is to load whatever "pagina" is after the opacity of #content is 0? You should use the complete parameter instead of asking if the opacity is 0:

function cargarContenido(pagina){

```
$('#content').animate({"opacity":"0"}, 1000, function(){

    $("#content").load(pagina, function(){

          $('#content').animate({ "opacity": "1" });

    });

});
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try using the additional arguments of animate:

```
$('#content').animate({"opacity":"0"}, slow, function() {
    $("#content").load(pagina);
    $('#content').animate({ "opacity": "1" });
});
```