# Load a fragment of code when div opacity = 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lot of images in the same page at the same position. There are groups that have `opacity = 0` (the div) and set the `opacity = 1` when want to show one.

But, obviously, all the images load at the beginning (93Mb).

So, I want to load the images at the request. Load the content of the div and the images that contain.

I started with this:

```
if($('#id_of_div').css('opacity') == 1) {
    loadTheCode();
}
```

And then I found this ( [load html after opacity = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396645/load-html-after-opacity-0) ) written by Rory McCrossan 2 years ago:

```
function cargarContenido(pagina) {
    $('#content').animate(
        { "opacity": "0" }, 
        function() {
            $("#loadimage").show(); // show a loading image
            // load content when opacity = 0 animation finished
            $("#content").load(
                pagina, 
                function() {
                    $("#loadimage").hide(); // hide a loading image
                    // make opacity = 1 when content has been loaded
                    $('#content').animate({ "opacity": "1" });
                }
            )
        }
    );
}
```

But, I don't know how does this jQuery function work, how to implement it and how do I have to rewrite the required code.

When the code loads, the images load too?

It's possible to do a MySQL request by PHP?

I'm so lost :S

Thank you a lot!

Comment: How do you set the opacity 1 to the group of the images? Do you have some button, menu? Can you give us a fragment of html code you use?

Comment: Do you want call some function if that div has opacity 1??

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` as a framework generally has the structure of function call plus a `callback` which is called as soon as the original function is successfully executed. Callbacks are a very widely used feature in `jQuery` and provide immense control over events and actions happening asynchronously.

So the code does the following,

1. Animates the `content` `DOM` element by moving its `opacity` property to 0. Since the duration is not specified it is by default **400ms** (which could have been a second argument).
2. Next comes the callback function. So after `jQuery` animates the `opacity`, the callback function is triggered where a loading placeholder is shown (`loadimage`).
3. The `.load()` function seems to call a URL stored in the variable `pagina`. After the load event is executed successfully, another callback function for the `.load()` called.
4. This routine now populates the `innerHTML` of the `DOM` element identified by `content` ID.
5. Loading placeholder image is hidden and the `content` is again brought to opacity 1 in **400ms**.

So, here you can call another endpoint on your server which you have created to return only partial page contents (probably an in-house `API`). That API would internally do whatever database queries need to be done based on certain payload of the data. (Note that you can also send some payload with the `.load()` call.)

Check documentations here:
[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)